# Values of the column with space in the name became NULL when uploaded in Snowflake through pandas to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm fairly new in using Snowflake.

I was uploading a table into the Snowflake with one of its columns having space in the name (e.g. 'Selected Figures' ).  I used pandas to_sql to upload it in the Snowflake.  It was uploaded, however, the values of that column with space in the name became NULL.  When I changed the column name and replace the space with an underscore ('_') and reuploaded it, the values did not become NULL.

Anyone knows why?  Do you know any list of to dos' and not to dos' in Snowflake when uploading tables using Python?

Comment: Known issue, but I don't know the root cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682467/inserting-dataframe-from-python-into-snowflake-null-issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting dataframe from Python into Snowflake Null issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682467/inserting-dataframe-from-python-into-snowflake-null-issue)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Gokhan Atil and Artyom Akselrod!

Comment: Hi, Gokhan Atil! Is the issue stated in any documentation? Would like to know where you found the solution.